# Separating values of an array in PHP

Tags: php

I am currently working on clean URL and stuck with this issue.
URL: http://localhost:8080/Pumps/Piston-pumps

```
$request_path = explode('?', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$path_info = array_values($request_path);
echo str_replace('/',' ',$request_path[0]); 
print_r($path_info);
```

above code gives below output :

Pumps Piston-pumps 
Array ( [0] => /Pumps/Piston-pumps )

Is there a way I can convert the above array into:

```
Array ( [0] => Pumps [1] => piston-pumps )
```

I need this to add onto my URL

Thanks in advance

Comment: add up some more array content, to check out what kind of possibilities may occur.

Comment: very simple, you should just explode again using a slash, explode("/", $path_info);

Comment: explode again with slash ('/')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is

```
<?php
$getUrl     = "http://localhost:8080/Pumps/Piston-pumps"; // in your case it is $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$request_path   = explode('?', str_ireplace(array("http://","https://"),"",$getUrl));
$expSlashes = explode("/", $request_path[0]);
$resultArr      = array_slice($expSlashes, 1, count($expSlashes));
print_r($resultArr);
?>
```

use of `explode` and `array_slice` would result you with your required output.

`explode` is used to split a string with a needle sub-string

`array_slice` is used to create another array with limited and required number of array content

Comment: Thanks @ameenulla..well understood ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try following code.

```
   $new_array = ();
   foreach($array as $k=>$v){
      //This u split by upper case
      $g = preg_split('/(?=[A-Z])/', $v);
      $new_array[] = $g[0];
      $new_array[] = strtolower($g[1]);
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use explode http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

```
explode('/', '/Pumps/Piston-pumps');
```